# Generate XML and XSD documents using one XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xsd, schema

I want to do an XSL Transformation on an XML document so that my XSLT will generate a new XML document attached to an XSD document. I'm asking if it's possible to generate two different types of documents using only one XSLT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XSLT 2.0 can create several result documents with a single transformation using `xsl:result-document`, see the spec https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#creating-result-trees. Also some XSLT 1.0 processors support an extension like http://exslt.org/exsl/elements/document/index.html supported in libxslt/xsltproc or like http://xml.apache.org/xalan-j/extensionslib.html#redirect in Xalan.

Comment: Thank you. I didn't know that I could use xsl:result-document several times with different formats.